# Requisição Ajax com parametro do tipo JSON usando Jquery 1.8.2

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json

Estou tentando fazer uma requisição ajax que envia uma lista de objetos, mas parece que nessa versão do Jquery 1.8.2 (não posso atualizar porque o sistema é legado e tem muitas funcionalidades usando essas versão), parece que nao reconhece o

***contentType: "application/json"*** ou ***data: JSON.stringify(obj)*** quando uso esses codigo a requisiçao nem chega no servidor, e quando tiro o contenttype o objeto chega nulo na minha controller:

```
 $("#results :input").change(function () {
        var type = $(this).attr("type")
        var id = $(this).attr('name')
        var obj = {}

        if (type == 'text')
            obj = { Unidades: listaGlobal, Id: id, Valor: $(this).val(), Type: type }

        else if (type == 'checkbox')
            obj = { Unidades: listaGlobal, Id: id, Selecionado: $(this).is(':checked'), Type: type }

        // JQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true
        $.ajax({
            url: "/parametrizacao/SetaValor",
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#results').html(result)
            }
        })


    })
```

Comment: Jhonatas, isso não tem relação com a versão do `jQyery`. A versão 1.8.2 suporta o contentType, que inclusive não faz validação, você poderia até usar `contentType: 'teste123'` que o jQuery iria passar adiante, simplesmente adicionando no `Content-Type` do header da requisição. Seu problema deve ser outro, o formato do objeto, ou a falta de setar na chamada ajax o `dataType: "json"`, faça um teste adicionando isso e verifique se seu objeto é compatível com o que o método está esperando

Comment: @RicardoPontual ah sim entendi o que disse, coloquei o dataType: "json" e a requisiçao chegou na minha controller, o unico problema é que o atributo Unidades (que é uma lista) foi enviada sem o valores nas propriedades, sabe o que poder ser?

Comment: Quando eu dou console.log na lista vejo que ela esta correta, mas nao chega assim no servidor

Comment: O que tem nesse objeto, uma lista de outros objetos ou só valores simples, tipo números ou strings, assim: `{['um','dois']}`?  Se for um objeto, tem que estar batendo certinho com o que tem no objeto da controller

Comment: é uma lista de objetos, conferir todos os campos estão iguais, so que vem com os valores default (aspas vazias para strings, e zero para int)

Comment: Pra ter certeza, vai nesse link http://json2csharp.com/  coloca seu `json` lá pra ver a estrutura de classe esperada

Comment: Esta idêntico @RicardoPontual não entendi ainda porque nao esta passando os valores para os objetos.

Comment: Sem ver o código da classe e o json completos fica difícil opinar, mas se a estrutura está igual, deve ser alguma coisa simples. Tente mandar essa lista com somente um objeto com um valor bem básico. Por exemplo se for propriedade string, "a" e veja se funciona, daí vai adicionando os itens aos poucos. Se não for, pode ser a sintaxe, o *case* no nome de uma propriedade por exemplo, com certeza é algum detalhe

Comment: @RicardoPontual descobri o que era cara, parece que o JSON.stringfy tem um certo limite de conversão, e eu tinha um lista com 83 objetos e por isso estava dando pau, a principio achei estranho que uma havia funcionando so que dessa vez estava usando uma lista com 50 itens apenas

Comment: Entendi, embora não me pareça ser um valor que vá gerar esse problema, tem que ver o objeto todo, pode ser uma limitação da string. Se vc usar o `[F12]` e inspecionar a requisição, dá pra ver o objeto que estás sendo enviado e ver se truncou o cortou alguma coisa só pra tirar a dúvida